# printing dates between two different dates in Java

Tags: java, date

I am trying to get dates between given two dates and days, for example

date range 20/04/2014 - 210/05/2015

between these dates I am supposed to print dates between Monday to Friday for example. here is the code I developed:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date startDate = (Date) formatter.parse("20/04/2014");
Date endDate = (Date) formatter.parse("10/05/2014");

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();

cal.setTime(startDate);
cal1.setTime(endDate);

while (!cal.equals(cal1)) {
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.MONDAY|| cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.FRIDAY) {
        System.out.println(formatter.format(cal.getTime()));
        System.out.println(formatter.format(cal1.getTime()));
    }
    //System.out.println(formatter.format(cal.getTime()));

}
```

What I am supposed to see is:

```
21/04/2014(Monday)    
22/04/2014(Tuesday)    
23/04/2014(Wednesday)    
24/04/2014(Thursday)    
25/04/2014(Friday)    
28/04/2014(Monday)    
29/04/2014(Tuesday)    
30/04/2014(Wednesday)    
01/05/2014(Thursday)    
02/05/2014(Friday)    
05/05/2014(Monday)    
06/05/2014(Tuesday)    
07/05/2014(Wednesday)    
08/05/2014(Thursday)    
09/05/2014(Friday)
```

but what I am getting is:

```
21/04/2014    
20/05/2014    
28/04/2014    
20/05/2014    
05/05/2014    
20/05/2014    
12/05/2014    
20/05/2014    
19/05/2014    
20/05/2014
```

Comment: Where is the part of your code that you expect to print the name of the day?  What is the purpose of the check for Monday or Friday?  Why do you do two printlns per iteration?

Comment: Hi Oli I am expect to see the code in while loop in print line. The purpose is that I need to list only the dates between every monday to friday. Just like the same use in ms outlook when you book a meeting.

Answer (score 2):

A few issues

- You're reusing the same `DateFormat` uses to parse the input data `String` which is missing the required day (`E`) pattern. Create a separate `SimpleDateFormat` with pattern `dd/MM/yyyy (EEEE)` to display the output.
- There is only output if the day is Monday or Friday, whereas there should only be output for a weekend day.
- Displaying the output for variable `cal1` is unnecessary

Example:

```
while (!calendar1.equals(calendar2)) {
    calendar1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    if (!(calendar1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY) &&
               !calendar2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY)) {
        System.out.println(outputFormatter.format(calendar1.getTime()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use EEEE to print day name..

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy(EEEE)");
System.out.println(formatter.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Comment: Hi Anirudha thanks for the help but I am getting exception:
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "20/04/2014"
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
 at com.example.gui.NewClass.main(NewClass.java:64)
Java Result: 1

Comment: @TugrulASLAN check out the edit..you need to format your date not parse it